# How to convert date time format coming from server to become usable in time-ago-pipe?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**Brief explanation:** My server is returning date, time in below format -

```
myDate2= '22-DEC-2017 03:22:11';
```

This format is not acceptable by `time-ago-pipe`. It gives `NaN`

**What it accepts is:** `myDate: String = new Date().toISOString();`

How can I convert `myDate2` to required format ?

`home.html`

```
<span>{{myDate2 | timeAgo}}</span>
<span>{{myDate | timeAgo}}</span>
```

Answer of myDate is correct and myDate2 is incorrect.

How can I convert myDate2 so that I get correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass your date string to date object

```
myDate2:string = new Date('22-DEC-2017 03:22:11').toISOString();
```